# How can I find what Crawled Property maps to what field?

Tags: search, central-administration

I'm looking at the Managed Properties in my search administration and I see several Crawled Properties associated with Search Property Names.  Is there any way to determine what fields those Crawled Properties are associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for SharePoint 2010?

If so - you should be able to click on a specific crawled property which takes you to the crawled property details page.  This page contains a listbox of all the mapped managed properties under the heading "Mappings to managed properties".

Answer (score 3):

While I was trying to find the answer, I realized it's not as simple as it seems because it depends on the underlying data source and protocol handler used by the crawler.

If you want to understand more about crawled properties, I recommend reading this excellent article: [Mystery Solved - Crawled Properties in SharePoint (Series)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/tags/crawled+properties/)

Answer (score 1):

in SharePoint 2010, i got the column name by clicking on the column in the document library and looking in the URL string for `'SortField=SAP_x0020_Order_x0020_Num'`. Then you can look up this column in the managed meta data. This way assumes you know the column you need the value of to make it a managed meta data value.

I could not find a way to do it from the Global Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The only was I know of is that if you have an ows_* crawled property it maps to the field with the same name, i.e. ows_mycolumn maps to the field called mycolumn.